# Convergence of an improper integral $ \log( 1 + 2\operatorname{sech}x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, divergent-series

Show that the following integral is convergent

$ \int_{0}^{∞} \log (1+2\operatorname{sech} x) dx $

I tried by replacing $\operatorname{sech}x$ with 
$ 2/ e^x + e^{-x} $

and then by using limit comparison test with $ g(x) = 1/x^2 $
But couldn't solve further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ 0\leq\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+2\operatorname{sech}x\right)\,dx \leq 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}\operatorname{sech}(x)\,dx =\pi $$
since $0\leq \log(1+z)\leq z$ for any $z\geq 0$. Actually

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\log\left(1+2\operatorname{sech}x\right)\,dx =\frac{\pi^2+4\operatorname{arccosh}(2)^2}{8}\approx 2.1008896. $$

Comment: Thanks ! But was there any fault in my approach?

Comment: @Anuj: you may use $\log(1+2\operatorname{sech}x)\leq \frac{2}{e^x}$ as Bernard did, but the function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ does not play any role there.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simple with *equivalents*: the positive function
$$\operatorname{sech}x\sim_{+\infty}\frac 2{\mathrm{e}^x}$$
and the integral $\;\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty}\frac 2{\mathrm{e}^x}\,\mathrm d x$ is convergent.